# use imce for images in articles but not within the editor

Tags: media, files

By default, there's an imagefield of for the article and by default, in this imagefield you are only able to upload a file from your local disc.

Now i've installed imce and i can manage different folders with diffrent files but how do i connect the imagefield from the article to get one of those files from the folderstructure? To get the popup and click through the folderstructure and get the certain file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [Filefield sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module. It allows you to select an existing file on the server.